# Python Redirection in the Shell

Tags: shell, redirect, python-2.7

I have had the following problem which both Google and the Python documentation cannot aid me.

Essentially, I want to be able to perform **redirection** at the command-line level using the **subprocess** library as in the following (using a **shell script**) so I can perform operations in that directory:

Example:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python    

from subprocess import call
call("cd", "/usr/local/bin")
```

However, **it doesn't change to that directory**. Does anyone know what I am missing? I will be most appreciative of any insight that anyone can give on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell started by `subprocess.call()` changes directory. And then it exits. Your script does not change directories. Try [`os.chdir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chdir) instead.